# Notification System - Socket.io or Ajax?

Tags: ajax, node.js, sockets, laravel, websocket

I'm using Laravel5 and, I want to create a notification system for my (web) project. What I want to do is, notifying the user for new notifications such as;

- another user starts following him,
- another user writes on his wall,
- another user sends him a message, etc,

(by possibly highlighting an icon on the header with a drop-down menu. The ones such as StackOverflow).

I found out the new tutorials on Laracast: Real-time Laravel with Socket.io, where a kind of similar thing is achieved by using Node, Redis and Socket.io.

If I choose using socket.io and I have 5000 users online, I assume I will have to make 5000 connections, 5000 broadcastings plus the notifications, so it will make a lot of number of requests. And I need to start for every user on login, on the master blade, is that true?

Is it a bad way of doing it? I also think same thing can be achieved with Ajax requests. Should I tend to avoid using too many continuous ajax requests?

I want to ask if Socket.io is a good way of logic for creating such system, or is it a better approach to use Ajax requests in 5 seconds instead? Or is there any alternative better way of doing it? Pusher can be an alternative, however, I think free is a better alternative in my case.

Comment: if you have 5000 users online, all 5000 will be hitting your server every 5 seconds using your proposed ajax alternative, where as the socket alternative would only be pushing notifications to the users that need notifications.

Comment: That's true, but which one is the optimum path to choose?

Comment: Depends on your usecase/resources.

Comment: The one as StackOverflow is using. Free is a better option in my case.

Comment: I, personally, would use websockets, because an ajax request being fired every 5 seconds is wasted resources for both the server AND the client, but you'll have to make sure your server can handle the workload.

Comment: I found a github project called [Notifynder](https://github.com/fenos/Notifynder). I think I will go with that

Comment: I'd use socket.io instead of websockets directly because it gives you a fallback to comet/ajax long polling in cases where websockets fail (old browser, old proxy etc.) Though from experience I can say that you must double check your server configs and make sure websockets work because socket.io will work even when websockets fail and you won't know you're not using websockets.

Comment: Alternatively you can check out socks.js instead of socket.io. It has a different API. Whereas socket.io attempts to make your communications code look like DOM-style events, socks.js attempts to emulate the plain websocket API even when websocket is not available.

Comment: @slebetman I want to ask if it would fall into any trouble if I use socket.io with high number of users?

Comment: You'd get into trouble quicker if you use ajax with high number of users. I recently converted a chat application to socket.io because ajax was killing our servers. In theory, websocket (or any permanent connection) will hit the max open filedescriptor limit. But on linux nowdays that limit is by default somewhere around 6 million (it used to be several thousand) and can be configured higher if that's not enough.

Comment: Note that 6 million is more than the total number of IPv4 addresses

Comment: There are 2^32 ipv4 addresses, which accounts for 4 294 967 296. Way more than 6 million hopefully!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few thoughts:

1. Websockets and Socket.io are two different things.

   Socket.io might use Websockets and it might fall back to AJAX (among different options).
2. Websockets are more web friendly and resource effective, but they require work as far as coding and setup is concerned.

   Also using SSL with Websockets for production is quite important for many reasons, and some browsers require that the SSL certificate be valid... So there could be a price to pay.
3. Websockets sometimes fail to connect even when supported by the browser (that's one reason using SSL is recommended)... So writing an AJAX fallback for legacy or connectivity issues, means that the coding of Websockets usually doesn't replace the AJAX code.
4. 5000 users at 5 seconds is 1000 new connections and requests per second. Some apps can't handle 1000 requests per second. This shouldn't always be the case, but it is a common enough issue.

   **The more users you have, the close your AJAX acts like a DoS attack**.

   On the other hand, Websockets are persistent, no new connections - which is a big resources issue - especially considering TCP/IP's *slow start feature* (yes, it's a feature, not a bug).

   Existing clients shouldn't experience a DoS even when new clients are refused (server design might effect this issue).
5. A Heroku dyno should be able to handle 5000 Websocket connections and still have room for more, while still answering regular HTTP requests.

   On the other hand, I think Heroku imposes an active requests per second and/or backlog limit per dyno (~50 requests each). Meaning that if more than a certain amount of requests are waiting for a first response or for your application to accept the connection, new requests will be refused automatically.... So you have to make sure you have no more than 100 new requests at a time. For 1000 requests per second, you need your concurrency to allows for 100 simultaneous requests at 10ms per request as a minimal performance state... This might be easy on your local machine, but when network latency kicks in it's quite hard to achieve.

   This means that it's quite likely that a Websocket application running on one Heroku Dyno would require a number of Dynos when using AJAX.

These are just thoughts of things you might consider when choosing your approach, no matter what gem or framework you use to achieve your approach.

Outsourcing parts of your application, such as push notifications, would require other considerations such as scalability management (what resources are you saving on?) vs. price etc'

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. If I decide to have user2user notifications (userA added userB as friends), I'll need to have different channels for Pusher, it's likely to get expensive as I understand because of the 'max channel connections'. For the Ajax option, I think I can put 15-20 seconds instead. Which option would you pick?

Comment: I would go with writing my own Websockets implementation using a Redis server right from the start. I believe that this will make scaling up easier in the long run. I think time spent writing the code and paying a yearly price for a certificate (optional, for `wss`) would be better than the price for outsourcing in the long run. I wouldn't settle for AJAX unless I was limiting the app to a small client base.

Comment: So, Socket.io + Nodejs + Redis + Laravel seems to be my best pick. Do you think it'll break if I have a lot of channels? Maybe let's say 5000..?

Comment: I'm not into PHP, so I think I would choose Rails or Node.js also for the html layer. I would possibly consider an SPA, although that is not the best solution for everything.

Comment: Lastly, how should be the logic of the notification system user2user. Users get connected to the websocket as soon as they load every page, and server is the listener. As soon as a user triggers an action, server will be notified and send a 'run an event' call to other user, and an event (broadcast event) will be called. Am I on the right track? _*Or*_ do I need to create private channels for everyone separately depending on the userIds?

Comment: Broadcasting is very resource intensive as you scale up... I would implement a unicast system where only that user is alerted. Personally I would have a channel for every server instance and I would implement the unicasting from that channel. I think this is a better design than a channel per user (which will run you down on resources at the Redis server / main channel hub).